# "Page Not Found" with Netlify and React JS (_redirects is not working)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, netlify

So recently, I hosted my project on Netlify; thing was, the `react-router` would not work with it.

Now, I know *tons* of people have had this same issue, and they solved it with the `_redirects` text file...and put `/* /index.html 200` in it.

I tried that, with [this article](https://dev.to/rajeshroyal/page-not-found-error-on-netlify-reactjs-react-router-solved-43oa), and I still have the same isssue.

..and that's my problem.